# How do you a make a class property read-only, from outside the class, in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop

How can I make a property of a MATLAB class such that it can be read from outside the class but cannot be set from outside the class?  For example, I want the `sensor` property (below) to only be settable from within the Data class, while also being readable from outside it.

```
classdef Data   
   properties
     sensor;
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
classdef Data
    properties(SetAccess=protected, GetAccess=public)
       sensor;
    end
end
```

You can use `SetAccess=private` instead, if you don't want inheriting classes to have writeable access either.

The default behavior for `SetAccess` and `GetAccess` is `public`, so you don't need to explicitly state `GetAccess=public` here, but it does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html) for the properties - specifically the SetAccess property.